# LetsEncrypt cert works for HTTPS but not WSS

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, websocket

I installed a letsencrypt cert on CentOS 7 and get no errors when connecting with any browser with https://www.example.com. But trying web sockets wss://www.example.com:4445 produces ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in console window.

I haven't been able to google up a case where the cert works for HTTPS but not WSS. I know I must be missing some config somewhere. What could cause this?

Comment: Try using `https://www.example.com:4445` to point to the wss on port 4445 running on the server OS. Use wss over https that way instead and report back your results.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the WSS app looking for the cert in the wrong place.  It was pointing to an old self-signed cert.